# ARML $1994$ Polynomial Manipulation Question

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> (ARML $1994$)
>
> If $x^5 + 5x^4 + 10x^3 + 10x^2 - 5x + 1 = 10$, and $x \neq -1$,
> compute the numerical value of $(x + 1)^4$.

I came across this problem in a packet about polynomial manipulation and I couldn't find a way past expanding $(x+1)^4$ and subtracting it from the polynomial. I was wondering if any of you could explain it.

Comment: If you don't see the "trick" offhand, note that the problem gives away $x=-1$ as being a root of the equation. So, move everything to one side, divide by the factor of $x+1$, and compare the quotient to $(x+1)^4$.

Answer (score 5):

Remember your binomial coefficients, and notice that the left-hand side of the equation is equal to $(x+1)^5-10x$. So we can rewrite that equation as follows:

\begin{align*}
(x+1)^5-10x&=10\\
(x+1)^5-10(x+1)&=0\\
(x+1)\left[(x+1)^4-10\right]&=0 \, .
\end{align*}

Since $x \neq -1$, the first factor above is nonzero, so the second factor must be zero. That is, $(x+1)^4=10$.

Comment: This assumes that $x$ is living in some integral ring (which is not mentioned anywhere in the question).

Comment: ARML is a high-school math competition which doesn't even assume its contestants know calculus, much less ring theory. But if this bothers you, you should be complaining about the question, not my solution: in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, both $x=1$ and $x=5$ solve the equation, but $(1+1)^4=4$ and $(5+1)^4=0$.

Comment: I was adding a comment (which I believe was logically correct) rather than "complaining". Anyway sorry if this bothers you.